# How can I enter multiple keywords in a row in Photos 5 (Catalina)

Tags: photos, catalina, photos.app

When adding keywords to my photos in Apple's Photos app, I pull up the Info window, click in the Keywords field, and type them in. In previous versions, comma would commit the keyword but leave the cursor in the field so I could type another. So:

> park,sunset,dog,

would add three keywords. Since upgrading to Catalina, comma still commits the keyword but also (usually) removes focus from the keyword field. So anything I type afterward not only doesn't go in the keyword field, but is interpreted as keyboard shortcuts and does unpredictable things.

Clearly comma is no longer the right way to do this. So how can I add multiple keywords in a row to an image or group of images?

Comment: Sorry that I am not helping. Did you ever figure out the solution?

Comment: @Đôn-FelixRyżek Unfortunately no. There doesn't seem to be any way to add multiple keywords other than to keep clicking the keyword field. Several versions of Photos later this has not changed.